# Make a list flat

Tags: code-golf, ragged-list

Lists can contain lists and we have nested lists. But we don't like nested lists and want to flatten them. By flattening I mean create a list which does not contain any list, but elements of lists it contained before. I'll explain it more.

### Input

An arbitrary size list which has the below properties:

- it can contain integers
- it can be empty
- it can contain lists which have the same properties

These are some examples of valid lists:

```py
[]
[1, 2, 46]
[[], []]
[[[14], [[5]]], 4, [2]]
```

### Output

The output must be a list, which is empty or only contains numbers. It must not contain lists. The output must be the flattened version of the input.

- all elements (beside empty lists) must be in the flattened version
- the order matters

## Test cases:

```py
[[3],[3, [[6]]]] ->  [3, 3, 6]

[] -> []

[[], []] -> []

[[1, 4, 6], [1, [2, 67, [5, 7]]]] -> [1, 4, 6, 1, 2, 67, 5, 7]
```

Comment: Nice question, but it has already been [asked before](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/80096/flatten-the-array). I highly suggest using the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?answertab=active) when posting new challenges next time.

Comment: For what it is worth I think this is the better version of the challenge.  The other version has a bunch of arbitrary restrictions that don't contribute to the challenge.

Comment: @WheatWizard I don't see how the other one has a bunch of arbitrary restrictions. It just has some input constraints

Comment: @Seggan 1. Builtins are banned. 2. The input must be able to contain mixed types which is a huge pain for strongly typed languages. 3. Strings must be a type distinct from arrays of chars which also is just a huge pain.

Comment: @WheatWizard apparently I'm bad at reading challenges...

Comment: In that case, reopening this wouldn't be so bad

Comment: This is literally a built-in function in many if not most programming languages. How is this a code challenge?

Comment: @SebastiaanvandenBroek It's certainly not a builtin in *most* programming languages.  If you want to have fun choose a language where it's not, or choose not to use the builtin.

Comment: You say that the input list can have arbitrary size, and can contain lists of the same type. Must the input be a finite list? And must it be well-founded?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flatten the Array!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/80096/flatten-the-array)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Languages with built-ins

[HBL](https://github.com/dloscutoff/hbl), 0.5: `-` - [Try it online!](https://dloscutoff.github.io/hbl/?f=0&p=LS4_&a=KCgpICgxIDQgNikgKDEgKDIgNjcgKDUgNykpKSk_)

[Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), ~0.823: `f` - [Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyJmIiwiW1sxLDQsNl0sWzEsWzIsNjcsWzUsN11dXV0iXQ==)

[flax](https://github.com/PyGamer0/flax), 1: `F` - [Try it online!](https://staging.ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70kLSexYsGCpaUlaboWC92WFCclF0N5N9WjlaKjow11FEx0FMxidRRAzGgjINscSJvqKJjHgoBSLFQ9AA)

[Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 1: `c` - [Try it online!](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=Yw&input=W1sxLCA0LCA2XSwgWzEsIFsyLCA2NywgWzUsIDddXV1d)

[Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 1: `F` - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/t////0dGGOgomOgpmsToKIGa0EZBtDqRNdRTMY4EAAA)

[Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 1: `f` - [Try it online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJmIiwiIiwiW1sxLCA0LCA2XSwgWzEsIFsyLCA2NywgWzUsIDddXV1dIl0=)

[05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 1: `˜` - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//9Jz//6OjDXUUTHQUzGJ1FEDMaCMg2xxIm@oomMcCAQA)

[Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 1: `Ƒ` - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//2MT//6OjjXSMY3WijYxiYwE)

[J](https://www.jsoftware.com/#/), 1: `,` - [Try it online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8GCpaUlaboW21KTM_IVNKx1NBWMwVBFIVPPyBwiCVUDUwsA)

[Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 2: `FA` - [Try it online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLG51bGwsIkZBIiwiWzI7WzM7WzRdXTs1XSIsIjIgMyIsIi1wIl0=)

[Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 2: `.n` - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/Xy/v///o6GhDk1gdheho09hYIG0CZBrFxgIA)

[Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/) + [hgl](https://gitlab.com/WheatWizard/haskell-golfing-library), 3: `rtc`

[Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Attache), 4: `Flat` - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywpSUzOSP2fpmBl@98tJ7Hkv19qakpxtEpBQXJ6LFdAUWZeSUhqcYlzYnFqcXSajkI0l4JCdLRxrE60MZATbRYLBDogMQgJpIBMKNtQR8FER8EMJARkRhsB2eZA2lRHwRykjSs29j8A)

[rSNBATWPL](https://github.com/Radvylf/rSNBATWPL), 5: `crush` - [Try it online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJyYWlzaW4tYmF0d2FmZmxlIixudWxsLCJjcnVzaCIsIiQgKCgoMSwyKSwzLCg0LDUpKSw1LCgyLDMpKSIsIiIsIiJd)

[R](https://www.r-project.org/) (almost), 6: `unlist` -
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvu/NC8ns7jkf5oGiNLQ1FRW0LVTiI7lggqACUMdBRMdBTNNHQUYF0wbAcXMoWxTHQVzTRCA6Ifq0FEAMqDKQCpi/wMA)

[Clojure](https://clojure.org/), 7: `flatten` - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87JzyotSv2vUVCUmVeSk6eg8T8tJ7GkJDXvv7qGhqGCiYKZpgKQ1jBSMDNX0DBVMNcEg/8A)

[jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 7: `flatten` - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/z8tJ7GkJDXv///oaONYnWhjHYXoaLNYIOCKBqLoWCAfxI421FEw0VEwA/GBzGgjINscSJvqKJiDVAMA)

[Factor](https://factorcode.org), 7: `flatten` - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqVQnFpYmpqXnFqsl5KaWqBQUJRaUlJZUJSZV6JgzcVVrVCtYKxQCyZBbDMgGwz/p@UklpSk5v3XA6qpVYDyFPTAOmrBGF3UUMEErB/EqlYwUjAzB1KmCuYwIxHK/wMA)

[Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/) + [free](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-5.1.7/docs/Control-Monad-Free.html), 7: `retract` - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZHBatwwEIbvfoqB5GBDbGdbSulS@9ImEEiXUnIrIQy2ZIu1JCPJdEPaZ9@OLK26S0/W/P/MfDPjEe2eTdPxrbyCR1TDggODH6j2u6fXmVm4Kv9kZQlfGRdKOKGVhU7PgvXAjZbgRgZWL6ZjoPkaccMYSN0vE721AcesE2rwTUbnZrut6xG7PWGqMbArbYZ6Dlrty8sP1ab6WPe6s7U1Xf1FK2f0VH3TCvvqnjKq0ckp69Eh@BA4YAbQwPfFsPX5O@g5h/yUUBRZJpR1qGjY@0V1jqbj0LQpiKkF/BqZYdSFS5x9Cgw6aeCDPICKxMw9ILmhD9lNHIPEz9etlyjHn/ph9/iwuwsAf@LMMGewc7DdwrpmnCzODmW77njKSvyG@pG4GHXurmVog40W2raBaNINHDMec3GCPEKoZXmJxVDwcsY8afMoIkt6dQ2T4feVdHKup37NSZvJANQGpwkOUBHp4EkSDv/RJbFSh5eLu6e1k8/PN/cdwub//CNv4hmOEoWipF7ThWYjlIPrVP9zpWxuwq99F7/vb@DMPamf4ndz@/xcHP8C)

[Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 7: `flatten` - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY5NCsIwEIX3OcUsGwgZ/F0ILjyBZ4ht0kYnP6RjQcSz1ypV0NkM7zHve3NJTD6Oo7tGCMbHSsJdDIagsTYfSjE32IN57aOrBEzzEQupfvRSwerPWivYKNhKIYXIxUemWH252pFhtlOjBESoU2PBlRSgY879DvHyfo1MbHUqLZrscUrYnvE8BOy5IX@aj3SdiGzNPsUeZ67uOJB4jOMT)

[Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 7: `Flatten` - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73y0nsaQkNe9/QFFmXomCg0IaEFdXG@oomOgomNXqKICY1UZAtjmQNtVRMK8Fgv8A)

[Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org/), 7: `flatten` - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY3BCoMwEER/ZfGU4KZQbRU8BOJXCEsOOdQiRBM00Ft@Pd04h5k3MDDxDD581fXbSjHtPKnVu5Q@hzA4y0eZ1O6i364kyFithWkXXMO5uySaHEFpyDEfDZLBxUqJRNRbpB6BaLAsBu50ZzV6IrwQhsqM1DGPnG@Ese4tn/4B)

[Racket](https://racket-lang.org/), 7: `flatten` - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pMzk4t@a@ck5iXrlAE5nBp/E/LSSwpSc37r66hYahgomCmqQCkNYwUzMwVNEwVzDVB4D8A)

[Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/), 7: `flatten` - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY/LDoIwFET3/YpJ2GhyQ0V8kmBi/Iymi8ojGsWSUhd8fZWGAOJs58zcueZ9bZ0LcNF5gdLoKsHN2rpJOFf1PdfZI8x0xc0X42djVMvLp7K2eLEGKQQiwpoQQ2JUkJ4gekMy67kNYUvYEcSecJCe99zMkEx5viFYwpEQrYZuzw/F9J/tA5LVUGG/E3NN19G4q2sY8mrym4j7S93on@pFtHTuAw)

[Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 7: `flatten` - [Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?I2Glkq)

---

Feel free to add to this community wiki. The below is a template to copy the code and links into to add to the above list.

```
[<language>](<language URL>), <byte-count>: `<code>` - [Try it online!](<interpreter url>)
```

Comment: [Almost a built-in](https://tio.run/##lY4xDsIwDEV3TuExkUxDKbRTuYjlwSoNAkUNohXXDw7K1LJgWfIf3pP/Q94yD6/7c9lP8Tom3yfpL1L5IIup3cGmIU5zDGMV4s14Q9QwUoNA1LIOrMdacA4yodvybqVvhZ/6xiPWl8z/ezXCKRdRXSMdNXd6zwhd7l@8QiFoKMiXSB8). Not sure if it should go there.

Answer (score 11):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 39 bytes

```
f=lambda s:[s]*(s<f)or sum(map(f,s),[])
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TZBRasMwDIbffQrhl9lDGSzd0hGaXETxQ9bN1OA4oXYKO8te8jJ2mV6gt5lcEpgQ6Jf0YUv6_p2-0mkM5bL8zMkWb7cH2_h-eP_oIdYUzaOKB6vHM8R5UEM_KYtRIxm94td0bKSUgmhnkHYIRJVhg6IFyDl7ZYSge4WyIsOU-Zc_I7xkisssqWS95_iKsN-e2hgEFitw74v8ueX5PLgA6fgUJ--Skl3ogtS1AIcjNJAn_7z0Hv0GFK3UWsB0diEpq5zGcd1pO8Uf)

Found independently but very similar to @xnor's [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/80123/101374) to the linked question.

Comment: It could be argued that this is a slightly improved version of @xnor 's [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/80123/110555) from the dupe thread. Kudos to you if you came up with it independently, otherwise maybe worth linking to the other answer?

Comment: @jezza_99 I did come up with it myself, but I will still link xnor's answer. Thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 8):

## sh + coreutils, 8 bytes

`tr -d []`

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 22 bytes

```
\(x)as.list(unlist(x))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGiNNulpSVpuhbbYjQqNBOL9XIyi0s0SvPAVIWmJkTy5t40DbAImDDW1IHQOgoIQTNNEFBW0LVTUIgGygCRWSwXVBtUIhouABGF6tfELm2oo2ACNASmyhBKGwHFzKFsUx0Fc4S90VAdOgpABlQZSEUsxBMLFkBoAA)

`unlist` is an almost-built-in ([see the CW answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/248253/55372)) in R, as it doesn't correctly handle the empty lists - it returns `NULL`. Also, it returns a vector of values not a list, so we convert the result to list with `as.list`. Fortunately, `as.list(NULL)` results in an empty list as desired.

---

#### [R](https://www.r-project.org), <s>40</s> 38 bytes

*Edit: -2 bytes thanks to [@Dominic van Essen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95126/dominic-van-essen).*

```
\(x)`if`(is.null(r<-unlist(x)),1[0],r)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGiNNulpSVpuhY31WI0KjQTMtMSNDKL9fJKc3I0imx0S_NyMotLgBKaOobRBrE6RZpQ1XvTNMAyYMJYUwdC6yggBM00QUBZQddOQSEaKANEZrFcUG1QiWi4AEQUql8Tu7ShjoIJ0BCYKkMobQQUM4eyTXUUzBH2RkN16CgAGVBlIBWxEE8sWAChAQ)

Outputs a vector (empty for input without any elements).

Comment: When the input list(s) contain some elements, this (and R's ```unlist``` function) returns vectors (not lists), here of integers .  So it would be more consistent to return empty-vectors of integers when the input list(s) don't contain any elements.  Luckily, this is [2 bytes shorter](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGiNNulpSVpuhY31WI0KjQTMtMSNDKL9fJKc3I0imx0S_NyMotLgBKaOobRBrE6RZpQ1XvTNMAyYMJYUwdC6yggBM00QUBZQddOQSEaKANEZrFcUG1QiWi4AEQUql8Tu7ShjoIJ0BCYKkMobQQUM4eyTXUUzBH2RkN16CgAGVBlIBWxEE8sWAChAQ)...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen This gave me an idea...

Answer (score 4):

## [Whython](https://github.com/pxeger/whython), 31 bytes

```python
f=lambda l:sum(map(f,l),[])?[l]
```

#### Explanation

```python
f=                               # f is
  lambda                         # a function
         l:                      # that takes a single argument l:
               map(f,l)          # First, apply f to every element of l
           sum(        ,[])      # Then concatenate all the resulting lists together
                           ?     # If l is an integer, the map errors, so instead
                            [l]  # just wrap l in a singleton list and return that
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728PKOyJCM_b8GCpaUlaboW-9NscxJzk1ISFXKsiktzNXITCzTSdHI0daJjNe2jc2Ihqm6WJicWpxYr2CpEcylEx-oACSAJZEGYxiC2MRBHm8XGQsUMdRRMdBTMQDJAZrQRkG0OpE11FMxBarhiudLyixRAxipk5oHpYisuhYKizLwSjTQNEF9TE2I5zKkA)

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 58 bytes

```
f=\(x,z=0[0]){for(i in x)z=c(z,`if`(is.list(i),f(i),i));z}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGiNNulpSVpuhY3rdJsYzQqdKpsDaINYjWr0_KLNDIVMvMUKjSrbJM1qnQSMtMSNDKL9XIyi0s0MjV10kBEpqamdVUt1IS9aRpgSTBhrKkDoXUUEIJmmiCgrKBrp6AQDZQBIrNYLqg2qEQ0XAAiCtWviV3aUEfBBGgITJUhlDYCiplD2aY6CuYIe6OhOnQUgAyoMpCKWIgnFiyA0AA)

'Roll your own' `unlist`-like function in R.  Returns a vector containing all the elements of the input (nested-)list, or an empty numeric vector if the input doesn't contain any elements.

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <strike>169</strike> 166 bytes

```c
#include<ctype.h>
#define D isdigit(*c))
#define P putchar(
#define R while(*c&&!D c++;
main(char*c,int**v){c=v[1];P 91);R do{while(D P*c++);R P*c?44:93);}while(*c);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYzNCoMwEITvPkWKICbagq0Xm/5cfADxKjnImuqCTaWNliJ99nSltAuzDB8zA@sWwDkfDfRjow9gX4PedCfPb/QFjWY5w0eDLdpQAOd/XLBhtNDV9/CPSvbssNeUC4JVziCKpHet0YRLTECMxgox8RmOU5UoWbAs4bJkzW3@9nJWCCotjMw5TffZjsv3b5Ssc1QkxVW1VYr@olTRfQA)

Comment: Do the ```#define```s for ```W```, ```D``` and ```R``` actually save bytes?  It's difficult for me to check without an online test link, but swapping the ```W```s, ```D```s and ```R```s in the code for their ```#define```d strings seems to shorten the code to [149 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/185My85pzQl1Sa5pLIgVS/Djks5JTUtMy9VIUChoLQkOSOxSIMrNzEzTwPE1ErWycwr0dIq06xOti2LNoy1DlCwNNS0DtdKVlNTdFFI1ta2VkjJry7PyMxJ1VDILE7JTM8s0dBK1tRUCNACyqIpBYrZm5hYWRprWtdC9ACVWtf@/w8A)...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen I didn't check it that thoroughly, but you forgot to replace W and D in `#define R`. It might be possible to find a shorter arrangement with some tweaks though. I'll add the TIO link too

Comment: Ah, yes, you're right!  My mistake!  I hadn't twigged to the nested ```#define```s.  Well done, and welcome to code golf!

Comment: [160 bytes](https://tio.run/##PY3LCoMwEEX3fkWKIEm0BVs3Nn1s/ABxK1nIGHWgPrCppYjfnkYXDtwZOMzhwrEGMMbFduhHfQP9G9SpeThuqSrsFEkIvkusUVMOTOw4JcNHQ1OMdEeZqPqRCg6ed0gY@L7TFtjR9YlDgJ3mfGIz3Kc8lCIlccgyUfbzJiUs5dawxN5nFF3jCxPLt8GX2noXY6xlE@T5WUq710TSzh8 "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 350 bytes

```
-[<+>---]<++++++.[-]<,[>+<[>>+>+<<<-]>>>[<<<+>>>-]--[<->++++++]<-[>+>+<<<<[>>>>>+>+<<<<<<-]>>>>>>[<<<<<<+>>>>>>-]-[<->---]<------[<->[-]]<+<<<<[>>>>>+>+<<<<<<-]>>>>>>[<<<<<<+>>>>>>-]-[<->---]<--------[<->[-]]<[[-]<->]<[<<<.[>>>>+>+<<<<<-]>>>>>[<<<<<+>>>>>-]----[<-------->+]<[<<<<<[-]+>>>>>[-]]<[-]]<[-]<->]<[<<[>.>>][-]>>[-]]<,]>>-[<+>---]<++++++++.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pZBNCkIxDISv0n2bB4o/mzIXGbJQQRDBheD566Ttg4dbA03SNt@k6fV9ebzun9uzNWPNMDOvudtCpYXIlUBWqNUcAJVkRXMTYhjVXo2zKuqxIis1wckOPOje0LrFVj3V/w@RjQxjAIMSAQu3clONG60Yp8PTkAeol5iPkqE63apMLIAzFPtVUfL7lfrM1shdSYeSTl4SY9HD65B7nZ4VjyWdXfYF)

Works by ignoring brackets inside the outermost list. It makes sure not to print a comma after another comma.

Can probably be improved.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 53 bytes

```
⊞υθＦυＦιＦ⁼κ⁺⟦⟧κ⊞υκＦ⮌υ«≔⟦⟧ηＷι⊞η⊟ιＦ⮌η¿⁼κ⁺⟦⟧κＦκ⊞ιλ⊞ικ»⭆¹θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY@9DsIgFIXn9inuCAkOGrVDJwdHk0ZH0oE0tJCS/lHqYHx2vJDWxEGWcy6c8wGVElPVC@N94awijsFI87TuJyCOQlS96nV0wljSMiiMs4SXDFpKKWzFdive5SInKxFA4ZUmF2t108W8wkjyVNrIiI1Nhbx@wDGc/fQV9nX9/@IYbleMZmBoDtJY@d0IL3qnxaS7mTxmlOYmBrIPf6S595xz9EcGZyQGyw/oM9QTg6wMy@8W8wE) Link is to verbose version of code. Uses the same flattening code as I used in my answer to [Inverted ragged list](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/242174/) but I'll explain it in slightly more detail here.

```
⊞υθＦυＦιＦ⁼κ⁺⟦⟧κ⊞υκ
```

Push the input list and all of its sublists to the predefined empty list.

```
Ｆ⮌υ«
```

Loop over all of the sublists in reverse order i.e. deepest first.

```
≔⟦⟧ηＷι⊞η⊟ι
```

Remove the elements of the sublist and push them to a temporary list.

```
Ｆ⮌η¿⁼κ⁺⟦⟧κＦκ⊞ιλ⊞ικ
```

Loop over the elements of the temporary list in the order they were in the original sublist. For those elements that are sublists push their elements (which by now are just integers) to the sublist otherwise just push the integer element to the sublist.

```
»⭆¹θ
```

Pretty-print the final list so that you can see that it has been flattened.

Answer (score 2):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 34 bytes

```
f(a)=if(#a&&a!=b=concat(a),f(b),a)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMGCpaUlaboWN5XSNBI1bTPTNJQT1dQSFW2TbJPz85ITS4CiOmkaSZo6iZpQlamJBQU5lRqJCrp2CgVFmXlAJQpKII6SAsgMTR2F6Oho41idaGMQyywWCIAMEAYTYF60oY6CiY6CGYgNZEYbAdnmQNpUR8EcpCEWahnMeQA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), <s>58</s> 55 bytes

```
lambda l:[*map(int,re.findall('\d+',str(l)))]
import re
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3zXMSc5NSEhVyrKK1chMLNDLzSnSKUvXSMvNSEnNyNNRjUrTVdYpLijRyNDU1Y7kycwvyi0oUilKh2jMLioA6NNI0oqONY3WijXUUoqPNYoFAU5OLCy6HyouOBapCUxFtqKNgoqNgBpICMqONgGxzIG2qo2AOMQ5i4YIFEBoA)

Thought it was a bit cheeky using regex to flatten the list

-3 bytes thanks to @Dingus

Comment: [49 with python 2](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728oLIkIz_PaMHiNNuYpaUlaboWNw1zEnOTUhIVcqxyEws0MvNKdIpS9dIy81ISc3I01GNStNV1EnISNDW5MnML8otKFIpSoRozC4qAqjXSNKKjjWN1oo11FKKjzWKBAKiWCy6HyouOBapCUxFtqKNgoqNgBpICMqONgGxzIG2qo2AOMQ5i4YIFEBoA)

Comment: and without regex, [42](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3tdJscxJzk1ISFXKscrQMbG0NEvNSonNi84sUiktzNXITCzTSdHI0daJjNaE6MguKMvNKNNI0oqONY3WijXUUoqPNYoFAU5OLCy6HyouOBapCUxFtqKNgoqNgBpICMqONgGxzIG2qo2AOMQ5i4YIFEBoA), and [41 with python 2](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728oLIkIz_PaMHiNNuYpaUlaboWNzXTbHMSc5NSEhVyrHK0DGwME_NSonNi84sUiktzNXITCzTSdHI0daJjNaEaMguKMvNKNNI0oqONY3WijXUUoqPNYoFAU5OLCy6HyouOBapCUxFtqKNgoqNgBpICMqONgGxzIG2qo2AOMQ5i4YIFEBoA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Javascript (node)](https://nodejs.org/en/), <s>70</s> <s>49</s> 47 Bytes

- -21 Bytes thanks to [Matthew Jensen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/87728/matthew-jensen)!
- -2 Bytes thanks to [Dom Hastings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9365/dom-hastings)!

```javascript
f=(a,c=[])=>a.map(a=>a.map?f(a,c):c.push(a))&&c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY3dCsIwDEbvfYpejRZih043EKoPEnoR6uYPcy1Wff2aSgVRDIF85BySMz0ouusp3OaT3/cpDUYSOINWmS3pCwVJJeyGTNTG6XCPR0lKVZVLzk/Rj70e/UEOErGxgA0IxNZyKSXqWuQFd2tnX/ab/wC0fML@xwsQq3yQLY645NzxXIPoPt4WCwSHoryM9AQ)

Comment: [-21 bytes](https://tio.run/##dY3RCsIwDEXf/Yo@jQRih043EDo/JPSh1E0n2zqc@vs1GxNEMYTkknu4ubqnG/2tGe7rPpyqGGsDjrxhi6YEpzs3HOcJjSlraMgjHrweHuMFHGKS@OhDP4a20m04Qw3MmSXOSDHnVgpRpamaDtK5XX3Rb//HYCsR9r@9IbWbAoUSyVvRhew9qeLj7UKRErEgMxFf), you can check whether `a` is an array by testing the truthiness of `a.map`, you also don't need the `.flat()` or `|c` in there. You've also got a trailing space :)

Comment: Instead of ternary, you can write `a?.map(i=>f(i,c))??c.push(a)` -- Assuming `?.` & `??` operators are supported/allowed. Saves 4 characters.

Comment: @AjitPanigrahi That doesn't work, you instead need `a.map?.()`. [Try it online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70kLz8ldcGCpaUlaboWN_XSbDUSdZJto2M1be00EvVyEwvs9TQybe3SNDJ1kjU17e2T9QpKizM0EjU11dSSobq2JOfnFefnpOrl5KdrpGlERxvH6kQb6yhER5vFAoGmpoK-vgJIAIjMYrnQVMPkMSSiY4FGxOKWNtRRMAEZCFQFZEYbAdnmQNpUR8EcyVqoKh0FIAOqBKwC4naYzwE)

Comment: You can save a couple more bytes re-ordering the conditional check: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY3dCsIwDEbvfYpejRZih043EKoPEnoR6uYPcy1Wff2aSgVRDIF85BySMz0ouusp3OaT3/cpDUYSOINWmS3pCwVJJeyGTNTG6XCPR0lKVZVLzk/Rj70e/UEOErGxgA0IxNZyKSXqWuQFd2tnX/ab/wC0fML@xwsQq3yQLY645NzxXIPoPt4WCwSHoryM9AQ "JavaScript (Node.js) – Try It Online")

Comment: @DomHastings oooooh nice, just updated the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 13 bytes

```
#~Level~{-1}&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7X7nOJ7UsNaeuWtewVu1/QFFmXkm0sq5dmoNyrFpdcHJiXl01V3WtDle1oY6RjokZiAXkVteCGdWGJkB2tWktkGuiU20EETUGihkDhc1qa8ECqHoMgSqBxgDpaiMdM3OdalMdc5BCrtr/AA)

Not the built-in. Returns all atomic expressions, in order.

---

#### [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 11 bytes

```
##&@@#0/@#&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7X1lZzcFB2UDfQVntf0BRZl5JtLKuXZqDcqxaXXByYl5dNVd1rQ5XtaGOkY6JGYgF5FbXghnVhiZAdrVpLZBrolNtBBE1BooZA4XNamvBAqh6DIEqgcYA6WojHTNznWpTHXOQQq7a/wA)

Returns a `Sequence` instead of a `List`.

#### [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 6 bytes

```
#<>""&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7X9nGTklJ7X9AUWZeSbSyrl2ag3KsWl1wcmJeXTVXda0OV7WhjpGOiRmIBeRW14IZ1YYmQHa1aS2Qa6JTbQQRNQaKGQOFzWprwQKoegyBKoHGAOlqIx0zc51qUx1zkEKu2v8A)

Returns a `StringJoin` instead of a `List`, and an empty string when there are no elements (as `StringJoin[]` evaluates to `""`).

Answer (score 2):

## [Javascript](https://nodejs.org/en/), <s>96</s> 83 bytes

```javascript
f=a=>JSON.stringify(a).replace(/[\[\],]/g,' ').split(/\s/).filter(e=>e).map(e=>e-0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY3BCsIwDIbvPkVva6G26nQ7bQ/gQQ8esx7K7EalrmUdgk8/szFBFEMgH/k/kpt@6Fj3Ngzrzl/NODaFLsrj5XwSceht19rmSTUTvQlO14ZKqKBSXMmWJyRhIgZnByqrKJlorBtMT01RGibuOsy03rCx9l30zgjnW9pQgFRxSDkByBQWY0RKMi2wM7X6st/5TwAKT6j/8ZaT/XQQLUTYIec4D5zkH28XixOERZmN8QU)

Comment: You can save bytes by filtering for `e=>e` because '0' is truthy. And to convert a string to int you can use `e-0` instead of parseInt

Comment: @Falco `+e` works, and also the `[]` in the regex don't need escaping if placed correctly.

Answer (score 2):

## Scala, 75 bytes

```scala
def f(l:List[_]):List[_]=l.flatMap{case n:Int=>List(n)case p:List[_]=>f(p)}
```

My first Scala answer! With a lot of help from @user.
[Try it online!](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/m3aMNAlYS5CfEL77Gt12sQ)

Comment: Use [Seq](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/7WlmWLq5RKSyhKU8TinfVw) (a supertype of `List`) to save some bytes. Also, swapping the cases means you don't need to add `:Int`.

Answer (score 2):

## BQN, 8 bytes

```
∾⍟(¯1+≡)
```

[Try it here!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAg4oi+4o2fKMKvMSviiaEpCgoo4oCiU2hvdyBG4oiY4oCiSnMpwqgg4p+oCiJbWzNdLFszLCBbWzZdXV1dIgoiW10iCiJbW10sIFtdXSIKIltbMSwgNCwgNl0sIFsxLCBbMiwgNjcsIFs1LCA3XV1dXSIK4p+pCgpA)

Thanks to @Razetime for 6 bytes saved!

### Explanation

- `...⍟(¯1+≡)` repeat (depth - 1) times...
- `∾` join (same effect as flattening 1 level)

Comment: `∾⍟(¯1+≡)` without recursion (not checked on all cases)

Comment: note that `•Js` can help you read JSON arrays into bqn arrays

Comment: @Razetime thanks! Seems to work for all cases I've tested so far.

Answer (score 2):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), <s>62</s> 38 bytes

*Thanks [@Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan) for a staggering -24 bytes!!!*

```
L+X:-maplist(+,L,M),append(M,X);X=[L].
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYrLCoMwFER/JbhKyCi0tgqWCu7jPnDJQugDQc1Fhe7y62nsprOYOQOHVz/5d759xhiNtk0@DzyN2y41DHqFgfm5PGQPq272TsYV8e9Q59pWdtri5dd52GUWWOStCByWDNTBOqVARKUDlRBElUtJkD799ig6QVwgqoMT0jlxnfYKUR@@U0X8Ag)

There's probably a builtin out there which flattens lists, but here's a non-builtin way of doing it.

Comment: yep: https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=flatten/2 nice!

Comment: `[A,B]>>(A+B)` can just be `+`, and you don't need parens around `maplist(+,L,M),append(M,X)`.

Comment: And you can remove `is_list(L),` - the goal will fail if it's not a list, resorting to `X=[L]` (also beats joking).

Ends up in 38 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYrLCoMwFER/JbhKyCi0tgqWCu7jPnDJQugDQc1Fhe7y62nsprOYOQOHVz/5d759xhiNtk0@DzyN2y41DHqFgfm5PGQPq272TsYV8e9Q59pWdtri5dd52GUWWOStCByWDNTBOqVARKUDlRBElUtJkD799ig6QVwgqoMT0jlxnfYKUR@@U0X8Ag "Prolog (SWI) – Try It Online")

Comment: @Steffan wow you should post as your own answer, that's like way different from my answer.

Comment: it's the exact same answer but golfed lol. post it urself

Comment: @Steffan Ok then, if you insist... It's a pretty substantial golf though

Answer (score 2):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 45 bytes

```
[A|L]+B:-A+X,L+Y,append(X,Y,B).
[]+[].
A+[A].
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYvNCoMwEITvPkXwlJBNoLVV8CDEsw@gLHsQ@oOgJqjQS/HV003nMPMNzITNz/5t9s8UI7pvR7qtjdM9dHqAMYTn@pA9DNAqmyFpJJs5jY5srM0yhnnaD8m1aWQ6vfy2jIfMzyBMI85wrjmgg56UAkQsCLAAgVgSi4E7/jMZXkDcQJSJGfHKXHHeQVRpT8rGHw)

Uses pattern matching to decompose and recursively call the function on the head and tail of the list.

#### Explanation

```
[A|L]+B:-                         # Match on list input with at least one input
         A+X,                     # Recursively call on the head of the list
             L+Y,                 # And on the tail
                 append(X,Y,B).   # And combine the results together
[]+[].  # If the element is just an empty list, return the same
A+[A].  # If it just a single element, return a singleton list
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <s>114</s> <s>99</s> 89 bytes

- -15 bytes with help from @ceilingcat

```c
main(c,v)char**v;{for(;v;c=!printf(v?c?"[%s":",%s":"[]"+!c,v))v=strtok(c?v[1]:0,",[ ]");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HctBCoMwEADAr9SFQqIp2Ksh5CFLDmHBKtWkJGEv4ttX7GVuQy/aYvqI7HFNigxrWmLpe7bHnIuybMl1v7KmNiv25AGfFSYwfzHA0N1Hs6uttPxV5BnfYRoNGHwE0PYUEQwX)

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 30 bytes

```javascript
a=>eval(`[${a}]`).filter(x=>1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/R1i61LDFHIyFapTqxNjZBUy8tM6cktUijwtbOUPN/cn5ecX5Oql5OfrpGmkZ0tHGsTrSxjkJ0tFksEGhqKujrK4AEgMgslgtNNUweQyI6FmhELG5pQx0FE5CBQFVAZrQRkG0OpE11FMyRrIWq0lEAMqBKwCr@AwA)

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 39 bytes

```javascript
a=>((a+'').match(/\d+/g)||[]).map(eval)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY3NCsIwEITvPsXeuqGxQavtqb7ImkNIf1RiU2zpqe8eN1JBFJeFHWY@Zm9mNqN9XIdp2/u6CW0VTHVCNGmSiOxuJntBda5T1YllIR2tAZvZOBGs70fvmsz5DlskyrWkXAJRoXmEAKUgGryF3nzR7/wnIM0V@n@8k3CIhUyxpD3rku9RQvnxdqUksFiRFxGe)

Assume no negative input

Answer (score 0):

## [APL(Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), 1 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```
∊
```

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=e9TRBQA&f=S3vUNzWrOD9PQT06OtrQJFZHITraNDYWSJsAmUaxseoA&i=AwA&r=tryapl&l=apl-dyalog&m=train&n=f)

Comment: I think it's 3 bytes, not 1 byte.

Comment: Why not just add this to the list of built ins?

Comment: @AmirrezaRiahi it uses a custom encoding where each character is one byte

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript 46 bytes

```
f=a=>(a+'').split(',').filter(x=>x).map(s=>+s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY3BCsIwDIbvPkVvbVnt0Ol26l4k9FBmK5W6jrXI3r5mMkEUQyAf@T@Sm3mYNMx@yvsxXmwpThnVM1NRymWags@MCkTnQ7YzW1S/cHk3E0uqrxIvQxxTDFaGeGWOATRaQCMIQKuxOCd1TdYFdqt3X/Y7/wlA4wn9Pz4IcloPooUIR@QO51mQ7uPtZgmCsCkvozwB)

Uses the trick that stringification of arrays unnests all arrays. After that empty elements need to be removed and the result mapped to integers.